# How to get the number of the word on window selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble on getting the number of the word on window selection in jQuery

Here's a example I have coded up

```js
    $(".highlight_text").on("click", function(e) {
        
         var text = window.getSelection();

        // For diagnostics
        var start = text.anchorOffset;
        var end = text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset;

        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

        var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");

        

        span.appendChild(selectionContents);

        span.style.backgroundColor = "#FCEE4F";
        span.style.color = "black";
        
        var span_text = span.textContent;
        $(".note_details").children(".blue_submit_button").attr("id", span_text);

        range.insertNode(span);


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <button class="highlight_text">Highlight</button>
</div>
```

Its a very simple word highlighter

but is their a way to have it so when a user highlights a word it says the number of the word

For example

My name is bob

if the user highlights name

it should come up with 2 because the word name is the second word in the sentence

**Any help would be much appreciated**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you to resolve your query

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".highlight_text").on("click", function (e) {

                var text = window.getSelection();
                if (text) {
                    // For diagnostics
                    var start = text.anchorOffset;
                    var end = text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset;
                    var overallText = $('.text').text().split(' ')

                    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
                    var span = document.createElement("span");



                    span.appendChild(selectionContents);

                    span.style.backgroundColor = "#FCEE4F";
                    span.style.color = "black";

                    var span_text = span.textContent;
                    $(".note_details").children(".blue_submit_button").attr("id", span_text);

                    range.insertNode(span);

                    var count = 0;
                    var isCheck = false;
                    overallText.forEach(function (e) {
                        e = e.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '');
                        // remove empty space and breaklines
                        if (e && !isCheck) {
                            count++;
                            if (e == span_text.trim()) {
                                isCheck = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    $('#count').text(count)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <button class="highlight_text">Highlight</button>
    </div>
    <div id='count'></div>
</body>

</html>
```